# Joining two tables in Microsoft Report Viewer (SSRS 2012)

Tags: c#, reporting-services

I have two database tables

Invoice Table (PK InvoiceNo)

```
InvoiceDate | InvoiceNo |  Name |  Class | AmountPaid
  2014-6-5  |   B001    |  ABC  |   E1   |   1500.00
  2014-6-5  |   B002    |  BCD  |   E1   |   2000.00
  2014-6-5  |   B003    |  CDE  |   E3   |   1000.00
  2014-6-5  |   B004    |  ABC  |   E3   |   3000.00
  2014-6-6  |   B005    |  BCD  |   E2   |   5000.00
  2014-6-6  |   B006    |  CCD  |   E1   |   2000.00
```

Expences Table (PK Date,Description)

```
    Date    | Description |  Cost 
  2014-6-5  |  Lunch      | 150.00 
  2014-6-5  |  SoftDrink  |  50.00 
  2014-6-6  |  BusFair    |  10.00
```

I want to create a report using these two tables. What I expect is

```
InvoiceDate | InvoiceNo |  Name |  Class | AmountPaid | Description  |  Cost 
  2014-6-5  |   B001    |  ABC  |   E1   |   1500.00  |   Lunch      | 150.00
            |   B002    |  BCD  |   E1   |   2000.00  |   SoftDrink  |  50.00
            |   B003    |  CDE  |   E3   |   1000.00  |     
            |   B004    |  ABC  |   E3   |   3000.00  |
  2014-6-6  |   B005    |  BCD  |   E2   |   5000.00  |   BusFair    |  10.00
            |   B006    |  CCD  |   E1   |   2000.00  |
```

But my output looks like this

```
 InvoiceDate | InvoiceNo |  Name |  Class | AmountPaid | Description  |  Cost 
  2014-6-5  |   B001    |  ABC  |   E1   |   1500.00  |   Lunch      | 150.00
            |   B002    |  BCD  |   E1   |   2000.00  |   Lunch      | 150.00
            |   B003    |  CDE  |   E3   |   1000.00  |   Lunch      | 150.00
            |   B004    |  ABC  |   E3   |   3000.00  |   Lunch      | 150.00
            |   B001    |  ABC  |   E1   |   1500.00  |   SoftDrink  |  50.00
            |   B002    |  BCD  |   E1   |   2000.00  |   SoftDrink  |  50.00
            |   B003    |  CDE  |   E3   |   1000.00  |   SoftDrink  |  50.00
            |   B004    |  ABC  |   E3   |   3000.00  |   SoftDrink  |  50.00
  2014-6-6  |   B005    |  BCD  |   E2   |   5000.00  |   BusFair    |  10.00
            |   B006    |  CCD  |   E1   |   2000.00  |   BusFair    |  10.00
```

Please help me to resolve this problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're running into 2 problems here:

1. You need to add an SSRS Group for both InvoiceDate and Description, and configure the Description field on the table in the same manner that you seem to have already done for InvoiceDate (so it only appears on the group row, not in the details).
2. Your "Expences" table should NOT be using Date + Description as a PK.  It should have its own "ExpenceID" type field, and an "InvoiceNO" FK back to your "Invoice" table.  Without proper keys, joining only on "Date" is going to cause a cartesian.

Note that #2 is more critical than #1 - until you fix your data issue, you're going to have a bad time.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mr. Kyzen. I did it. Thankx for the opinion.